# binding knockout bindings to an MVC razor model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, knockout.js

I have the following in knockout

```
     <select multiple="multiple" height="5" data-bind="options:allItems, 
 selectedOptions:selectedItems"> </select>
```

The above generates a list of all the items in the "observableArray" in the knockout script.

I need to somehow bind this, almost as if it were an @html.etc element in razor.

For example, I have the following

```
     @using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitFull", "ENCOUNTER", null))

         {

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Name)
      @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
      <fieldset>
         <legend>ENCOUNTER</legend>
         <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date)
        </div>
```

So when I click the button at the bottom of my page, the model that I defined at the top of the view

```
     @model MVC_MONGODB.Models.PATIENT.Patient
```

will be loaded up now with a "Date" property and a "Name" property.

**I need to also load up with model with the values from the knockout observableArray.**  I have never done this before, I'm not sure what the best way to do it is, or even *any* possible way, I'm not even 100% sure it's possible.

http://knockoutmvc.com/ seems like a promising reference.

Using "ValueUpdate" seems like a possibility or maybe a (input type="hidden") element somewhere..

I want to basically have the textbox from the knockout code I mentioned at the top of this question, to act as if it was actually inside

```
 @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.ChiefComplaintsStr, 5, 100, new { 
  HtmlAttributes = new { } })
```

Answer (score 1):

you can set the knockout related attributes using the `HtmlAttributes` of the controls like...

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ChiefComplaintsStr, htmlAttributes: new { @data_bind = "put knockout binding here"})
```

Comment: And is there a way to make that TextAreaFor hidden?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by that? please clarify

Comment: The code you mention above should generate a textbox loaded up with the values of the knockout binding, right?  If so, I actually need to hide the box from the user, because the user can already see the items from the knockout binding inside a knockout-generated box

Comment: maybe put the code you mentioned inside a div, and have css hide it using display attribute?

Comment: Then why not just use a hidden input tag. ie: `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ChiefComplaintsSt)`

Comment: Can I bind the knockout bindings to a hiddenfor?